# An image in cell of collection view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm displaying images from a parse backend in a collection view.

In CollectionViewController i have this working code:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var collection: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    println(numberOfDistinctValueInTypeOfStore)
    return numberOfDistinctValueInTypeOfStore
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {       
    let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell       
    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()     
    return cell
}
```

I want to add an image to the cell.
So i change the method to this, the app crashes:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {       
     let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell     
    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()     
    return cell
}
```

And even if the CellCollectionViewCell is empty like this. It will crash without an error message

```
class CellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {   


}
```

Normally i would add an outlet to the imageview inside the cell.

The error gives a breakpoint at this code

```
let cell:CellCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

as CellCollectionViewCell

Comment: Have you properly registered your `CellCollectionViewCell` class for reuse?

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell:CellCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(**reuseIdentifier**, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

It should be a string, and you have to set this identifier in the storyboard.